# Finding a model for a machine learning problem with a sensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, sensors

I'm doing a project where I have data of 100 sensors and its cycles  until it breaks. It shows a lot of characteristcs until its failure, and then shows it for the replacement sensor. With this data, I have to built a model where I can predict for how long the sensor will work until its failure, but only with a few data, not the full cycle. I have no idea what machine learning model is suitable for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of problem you are describing is known as survival analysis. A wide range of both statistical and machine learning methods are available to help you solve these type of problems.

What is great about these methods is it also allow you to use data points where the event you are interested in has not occur. In your example, it means you can possibly extend your dataset by including data from sensors which has not failed yet.

When you look at the methods I suggest you also spend some time examining how to evaluate these types of models, since the evaluation methods are also slightly different then in typical machine learning problems.

A comprehensive range of techniques is available at: http://dmkd.cs.vt.edu/TUTORIAL/Survival/Slides.pdf